# How to use Minion Pro math and text in latex?

Tags: fonts, installing, typography, minionpro

I noticed most posts about this are 10 years old. How can I install minionpro with math into LaTeX? I have the font files.

Comment: Two questions; 1. What system are you on and (b) Have you tried the old suggestions? One of LaTeX"s strengths is its stability over time.

Comment: Windows 10. I tried the old suggestions and they were quite confusing. I couldnt find some of the folders they mentioned

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what exactly you have been doing and which latex you are using. Additionally do you actually have the font (just checking as we've seen users who though they could use the font just by installing the support files)

Comment: I am looking at https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub/blob/master/mpro-installation-guide-miktex.pdf. Everything goes fine until step 8. I cant find F:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.x\miktex\config on my computer. Am I looking in the wrong folder? I am looking in C:\Program Files... Is there a difference between C: and F:? It's also weird since on MikTex console it says theres a directory at C:\Program Files\MikTex but there isn't.

Comment: I just reinstalled MikTeX but for all users. Now that Folder shows up. I think thats where I went wrong before. I will try again now.

Comment: I keep getting the error "Font shape `TU/MinionPro-OsF/m/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead"